# Fluorescent light only flickers when I turn it off

Tags: electrical, fluorescent

My fluorescent light shows no sign of life when I turn on the light switch, but will flash on one end when I am turning off the light. I've checked the ends.

Comment: You say "I've checked the ends" as if that means one thing and we all know that.  I don't actually, and I'm pretty good at fluorescents.  What exactly did you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is one of two problems. If you have another fixture with the same bulb, try switching the bulbs to determine if the bulb in question is bad. If you can't do this, then go to your home store and buy a new bulb (bring the old one with). Try it it the fixture and if it works, great, problem solved. If the problem still exists, then your ballast in the fixture is bad and you will have to replace it. You can usually get those at your home store too and they're easy to replace. The procedure to replace them depends on the type of fixture so we'd need a photo if you determine that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess I'm replacing the ballast then.

Comment: These days it's worth considering *changing to an LED bulb that does not need a ballast*, or *replacing the fixture with an LED fixture* as options, before committing to a new ballast.